# Replacing a string by a slightly variation of itself

Tags: python, regex

Example: how can I replace, for instance, 30.000 by 30000 with regex or any other Python method?

**Edit**: I think I didn't explain myself properly. The idea is not only to solve that specific example, but also: 30.100 by 30100, 39.200 by 39200... with a generic implementation

**Edit2**: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684190/python-replacing-a-string-by-a-variation-of-itself) I created again the fully-explained question

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Take a look to the edit, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a string by a variation of itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684190/how-to-replace-a-string-by-a-variation-of-itself)

Answer (score 2):

you can do in following way:

```
>>> a = "30.000"
>>> a.replace('.', '')
'30000'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\.', '', a)
'30000'
```

Comment: Thank you, Hackaholic. But that's not the answer I was looking for. My fault because, certainly, I didn't not explain myself. Take a look to the update, please.