# How to replace a string by a variation of itself?

Tags: python, regex

The idea is to replace numbers with themselves, but with any commas (`","`) in them removed from a text where there are also commas for separating sentences.

**From** -> `"This is a test with the number 21,938 followed by another sentence, with a coma"`

**To** -> `"This is a test with the number 21938 followed by another sentence, with a coma"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Remove Comma In Dollar Amount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180184/python-remove-comma-in-dollar-amount)

Comment: @Prune I don't think so, that's for if you only have the number as its own string, rather than the number in the middle of a larger string. OP wants to remove only commas that are in numbers, not all commas in the string.

Comment: @RandomDavis That's correct.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Hmmm ... okay, *I* see the solution quickly from that answer, but perhaps it's not that obvious ... thanks.

Comment: @MooingRawr In fact, all the answer are about writing code for the people who ask. I would like to know whether you had published that comment for this very same question being asked by other user with more reputation.

Comment: @Claudia I do post it to every time I see a lack of effort that request codes. Like the comment says, show effort on what you have tried and what went wrong. Rep or no Rep means nothing to me in regards of what I post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

text = "A long sentence, with commas, some in 10,000,000.00, some not."

re.sub(r'(?<=\d),(?=\d)', '',text)
# 'A long sentence, with commas, some in 10000000.00, some not.'
```

We look for commas `,` who are directly preceded and followed by a digit (`\d`). We don't want to capture the digits in the group that will be replaced, so we use:

> (?<=...)
>   Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by
>   a match for ... that ends at the current position.This is called a
>   positive lookbehind assertion.

and

> (?=...)
>   Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the
>   string. This is called a lookahead assertion.

See [Regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for reference.

Comment: I didn't know about the lookbehind and lookahead approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to capture the 3-digit groupings of digits which are followed by a comma, and then dynamically replace them:

import re

```
def RemoveCommas(string):
    numberRegex = re.compile(r'([0-9]{1,3},)')
    mo = numberRegex.findall(string)

    for innerString in mo:
        string = string.replace(innerString, innerString[:-1])

    print(string)
```

Then if I make the following call:

```
RemoveCommas('Hi, this is a number: 123,456,789 and here, is a trailing comma.')
```

I get this result:

```
Hi, this is a number: 123456789 and here, is a trailing comma.
```